# Navigation on the anonymous homepage is styled wrong

Tags: bug, design

[image]

This is what I observe. Watching from an ASUS laptop; an i5 intel CPU, and a chrome web browser (latest version). Well, I found an screenshot from a physics.SE user and it looks like this:

[image]

So apparently the code renders incorrectly in my Chrome. I can give further info about the system that I use. Note that I'm a guest while visiting the site. (if it helps)

Comment: Are you talking about the navigation (Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered, Ask Question) being off in the logged off screenshot?

Comment: Also - what OS are you on? This looks like a font issue and may be due to your OS/Browser combination.

Comment: Why did you delete post again on meta.stackexchange when your first question of this kind had been migrated to http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6578/weird-home-page-scenario-physics-se?